# Autoplay Brightcove Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, brightcove

I am using Lity.js to have a brightcove video link pop up in the modal window. My issue is the video is not auto playing, is there a working parameter that can used to say add to this link

`https://players.brightcove.net/1534342432001/ByfGnkzB_default/index.html?videoId=5806346414001`

So it can auto play, nothing i have tried works

Comment: chrome 66 automatically blocks videos autoplaying unless they are muted. I'm not sure if that's your issue though. Could you post some more code?

Answer (score 1):

looking on BrightCove's website, it seems you can add an &autoplay option at the end of your url. This worked for me in Microsoft Edge and Firefox. However, Chrome does disable this feature. The only way you could get this to work in Chrome  is to also mute the video by adding &muted to the end of the url like this. Hope this helps!

https://players.brightcove.net/1534342432001/ByfGnkzB_default/index.html?videoId=5806346414001&autoplay&muted

Also, here is the link to BrightCove's available query parameters:

https://support.brightcove.com/available-query-parameters-standard-iframe-embed-code#bc-ipnav-1

Comment: also, take a look at this article for a more detailed explanation from Google. 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 1):

You  can add an  id  to  brightcove  video  tag and  call  the play  function as added  in the script

videojs('videoId').play(); //'videoId' will  be  the  id  given to  player video tag